# I want to make method to replace all occurrences in string with a new variable using recursion

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I implemented this method which just replaces all the occurrences of a string (oldVar) with the new string (newVar) in the original String `f`:

```scala
def replace(oldvar: Var, newvar: Var): String = 
  f.toString.replace(oldvar.toString, newvar.toString)
```

Works fine, but I'm looking for a recursive approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version that works on strings. You should create a custom one that works on `Var` by delegating to my version after casting `Var`s to string:

```scala
def replace(old: String, neo: String)(f: String): String = 
    if f.isEmpty then
        f
    else if f.startsWith(old) then 
        neo + replace(old, neo)(f.substring(old.length))
    else
        f.charAt(0).toString + replace(old, neo)(f.substring(1))
```

Also edge cases such as empty values for `old`, `neo` and `f` should be properly handled by you to avoid "index out of bounds" or infinite recrsion errors.

Comment: It would be better if you didn't manipulate strings, like do the logic using `Array[Char]` and pattern matching, and then `mkString` out of it at the end, this way you could have better memory management and handle edge cases more easily.

Comment: @AminMal I completely agree, but then again, It would have been just better not to do recursion to solve this to begin with. I figured the OP is looking for learning value in their question, so I played along by writing the most basic and correct solution I could find using mathematical induction.

Answer (score 0):

This is cheating a little, but if you just want recursion ... (not really a fan of solving a straightforward problem in a runaround way "just because").

```
def replace(s: String, old: String, new_: String): String = s.indexOf(old) match {
  case -1 => s
  case x => s.substring(0, x) + new_ + replace(s.substring(x + old.length), old, new_)
}
```

Caveat emptor! This is *not* a *good* solution, just the easiest one that satisfies your (quite unreasonable) requirement.

A good one, would at a minimum be (1) tail-recursive and (2) not glue strings together like this (which is rather inefficient). But then, again, we already know that the *best* solution is to just call `.replace`, so ... why bother?